# Color automatically change with mobile darkmode

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

Can someone tell me why my color in `Xamarin.Forms` application changes if the target device has dark mode enabled.
here is my code :

```
<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{ AppThemeBinding Dark=#99f2c8}" />
```

and `AppShell.xaml` I set `FlyoutBackgroundColor` to `#ffff`

When my device is on light mode, we will see something like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GS7X.png)

and if it be on the dark mode we will see :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUrON.png)

my color will automatically come to dark. how I can prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Xiaomi by any chance?

When you enable the Dark Mode, a new menu appears: "More Dark mode options". There you can switch off "Adjust text and backgrounds automatically" to resolve the issue.

As far as I know Yoy cannot control these extra settings in Xamarin so as most of users won't be impacted.

Comment: yes, you are right, I'm testing it on Xiaomi. but if something like this happens in kotlin can we fix it with code?

Comment: Not sure if this will work for Xiaomi, but try set false to the 

`<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">true</item>` in **App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml**